# XslCompiledTransform strips new line characters inside CDATA without replacing them

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have source xml with this data:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="Body"><![CDATA[Line break 1\r\n\r\nline break 2\r\n\r\nline break 3\r\n\r\n Some more text.]]>
</field>
</add>
```

I am using XslCompiledTransform to transform it with this xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="add">
    <add>
        <xsl:for-each select="doc">
            <doc>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </add>
</xsl:template>
```

So the Body field should just pass through unchanged. The C# code to perform the transformation is as follows:

```
XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument();
StringReader reader = new StringReader("My source xml comes in here");
source.Load(reader);

XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
transformer.Load("xslt Path");

XmlWriterSettings settings = transformer.OutputSettings.Clone();
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
{
    transformer.Transform(source, this.xsltArgs, writer);
}

string transformedXml = builder.ToString();
```

The result of this transformation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<add>
<doc>
<field name="Body">Line break 1 line break 2 line break 3 Some more text.</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

As you can see, both the CDATA and line breaks have been removed. It's ok to remove the CDATAs at this stage, but I need to retain the line breaks. No matter which combination of the `NewLineHandling` and `NewLineChars` settings I use (or, indeed, if I omit them altogether), I get the same result.

Is there something else that I need to be doing?

Comment: What happens if you use `<xsl:template match="add"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="doc" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`?  (Alternatively, show your entire stylesheet.)

Comment: Think you are filtering them out with the select clause, do you need that at all? |text() as well might do the job can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: `\n` or `r` work in C# string literals as a way to include control characters, not within XML markup. So how does the XML look you are feeding to XmlDocument, does it have literal linefeed characters, does it have character references like `&#10;` or `&#xA;`? XML parsing includes some normalization http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends so preserving them is difficult but I don't see why you should not get any line break at all. Consider to show us minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tony `text()` is matched by `node()`.

Comment: There's loads more in the stylesheet that I didn't put on here to avoid too much noise in the question, I can put the rest in if you think it helps.

Comment: @Jibberish First examine what happens if you use the `<xsl:copy>` based template.

Comment: @Martin - the xml being fed to the XmlDocument is exactly as shown in the source xml snippet at the top; it contains \r\n

Comment: `\r\n` has no meaning in XML. It's four characters like any others. If you want newlines, there ought to be newlines in your source.

Comment: There are new lines in my source, they're getting removed during the transformation so something must known that they are some sort of special characters.

Comment: Well. For the third time now. What happens if you use the the <xsl:copy> based template I suggested in the first comment?

Comment: OK, I've figured this out with a variation of the xsl:copy suggestion from Tomalak, will post the fix as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by changing the xslt file, thus:

```
<xsl:template match="add">
    <add>
        <xsl:for-each select="doc">
            <doc>
                <xsl:copy-of select="field[@name = 'Body']" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </doc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </add>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@name = 'Body']" />

<xsl:template match="field[@name = 'Source']">
    <field>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">Source</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@name = 'Section']">
    <field>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">Section</xsl:attribute>
        BikesForSale
    </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@name = 'FirstSeen']">
    <field>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">PublishedDate</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </field>
</xsl:template>

...more here, removed for brevity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
source.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

right after creating the document, before you load it.

Alternatively supplement your XML with

```
<field name="Body" xml:space="preserve"><![CDATA[etc..
```